# AccessControlException while trying to create a directory on Azure

Tags: java, azure, azure-storage, azure-data-lake

I'm trying this to Create Directory in azureDataLake using azure data lake dependency

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
            <artifactId>azure-data-lake-store-sdk</artifactId>
            <version>2.1.5</version>
</dependency>
```

Using the following method:

```
private ADLStoreClient client; 
public boolean createDirectory(String path) {
        try {

            // create directory
            client.createDirectory(path);

        } catch (ADLException ex) {
            printExceptionDetails(ex);
            return false;
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            log.error(" Exception in createDirectory : {}", ex);
            return false;
        }
        return true;
    }
```

and I got this exception:

```
Error creating directory /gx-zweappdhd004/home/azhdipaasssh2/ADH/Compta/1458/1533632735200/RAPPORTS/
Operation MKDIRS failed with HTTP403 : AccessControlException
```

I checked the permission and I have all of them, so it's not related to the permissions.

**Update**:

To be more specefic the problem happening inside the method [isSuccessfulResponse()](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/datalake/store/HttpTransport.java#L98), and exactlly in this line [HttpTransport.java#L137](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/datalake/store/HttpTransport.java#L137) because the httpResponseCode equals to 403, can anybody explain this.

**Update2**:

I found that this line is returning the 403 status : [HttpTransport.java#L288](https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/datalake/store/HttpTransport.java#L288), I also tried to evaluate `conn.getErrorStream().read()` and I got this `stream is closed`, FYI this is bug occures sometimes and not always.

Answer (score 2):

I didn't reproduce your issue,you could refer to my working code:

```
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationContext;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.AuthenticationResult;
import com.microsoft.aad.adal4j.ClientCredential;
import com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLStoreClient;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.Future;

public class CreateDirectory {

    static ADLStoreClient client;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException, ExecutionException, IOException {
        setup();
    }

    public static void setup() throws IOException, ExecutionException, InterruptedException {
        String APP_ID = "<your app id>";
        String APP_SECRET = "<your app secret>";
        String dirName = "/jay";
        String StoreAcct = "jaygong";

        String authority = "https://login.microsoftonline.com/<your tenant id>";
        String resourcUrl = "https://management.core.windows.net/";
        ExecutorService service = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(1);

        AuthenticationContext context = new AuthenticationContext(authority, true, service);

        // Acquire Token
        Future<AuthenticationResult> result = context.acquireToken(
                resourcUrl,
                new ClientCredential(APP_ID, APP_SECRET),
                null
        );
        String token = result.get().getAccessToken();
        System.out.println(token);

        String account = StoreAcct + ".azuredatalakestore.net";
        client = ADLStoreClient.createClient(account, token);

        client.createDirectory(dirName);
        System.out.println("finish.....");

    }
}
```

[image]

Don't forget grant access ADL permissons to your client.

[image]

[image]

Hope it helps you.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I already setup the configuration and it's working, I just have a problem with this line https://github.com/Azure/azure-data-lake-store-java/blob/master/src/main/java/com/microsoft/azure/datalake/store/HttpTransport.java#L288 sometimes it returns 403, also this problem is not always happening sometimes it create the folder but sometimes it through an error.

Comment: @Svg_af  Sorry,I can't reproduce your capricious error on my side.I presume if your resource is public so the permission has any updates. If you adopt my above answer, you could voteup and mark it.Thank you.

Comment: @Jay_Gong sorry I already have this configuration this is didn't solve my problem.

Comment: @jay I am able to recieve the access token using this code, but getting the following  Exception in thread "main" com.microsoft.azure.datalake.store.ADLException: Error creating directory /adi
Operation MKDIRS failed with HTTP403 : AccessControlException
Last encountered exception thrown after 1 tries. [HTTP403(AccessControlException)]